# Realtime scenerios on dml and database class methods

Tags: apex, dml

can anyone provide links or tasks or whatever possibilities on dml operations otherthan force.com developer guide. plz...

As i understood concepts on insert,update,upsert,delete and also database methods also

Comment: sravanthi, what specifically is confusing you ? As it stands this question is very broad, and thereby quite challenging to answer. Please consider updating your answer with an example of what you do not understand.

Comment: my question is that i gone through force.com developer guide and i need some examples like using insertion,deletion

Comment: Have you already tried something out ? There are a lot of examples in the developer guide, so without knowing what you're confused it's hard to give you any examples that are better than those in the developer guide.

Comment: yes i gone through that book

Comment: but have you gone through the documentation (Apex Developer Guide) ? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm

Answer (score 1):

The force.com developer guide is a tutorial, for complete documentation and examples about apex, you can reference the [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm), it has a [chapter dedicated to DML](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm) .